# Most efficient way to traverse file structure Python

Tags: python, optimization, directory, subdirectory

Is using os.walk in the way below the least time consuming way to recursively search through a folder and return all the files that end with .tnt?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\data'):
    print "Now in root %s" %root
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.tnt'):
```

Comment: I suppose you could make a list comprehension out of it which might be slight faster as well as be slightly less typing. Don't forget what someone smart once said: ["Premature Optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth).

Comment: Using `os.walk` is a good way. Is it the _best_ way? I'm not sure. But I'm with [Voltaire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good) on this one.

Comment: Why would a list comprehension be faster? That would involve actually generating a list, instead of using this `os.walk` generator...

Comment: @nneonneo: OK, point taken -- a generator expression then.

Comment: its not premature optimization. I was just hoping there might be a way shave any time off

Comment: @user1580428: It's premature if you don't know if the time it takes is significant and whether _your_ time might be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: If it's not premature optimization, I gave an answer listing a bunch of possible ways to shave time off. They're all a whole lot more work, but if you really do have a performance problem worth putting effort into, what choice do you have but to do that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using `os.walk` is indeed the best way to do that.

Comment: how about os.scandir()?

Comment: @denfromufa: `os.scandir()` was added in Python 3.5 (*long* after this answer was posted). `os.walk()` was retooled to use `os.scandir()` though, so `os.walk()` is *still* the most efficient way to scan directories recursively.

Comment: the point is that for `python 2.7` you can install pypi package `scandir` provided by the author! it speed up my network directory scanning from 18 sec to 6 sec!

Comment: Ah, sure, but you didn't mention that you installed an external package! I'd then copy the [Python 3.5 `os.walk()` implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/os.py#l296) and use that instead of the 2.7 `os.walk()` function.

Comment: @denfromufa: even better!

Answer (score 3):

As everyone has said, `os.walk` is almost certainly the best way to do it.

If you actually have a performance problem, and profiling has shown that it's caused by os.walk (and/or iterating the results with .endswith), your best answer is probably to step outside Python. Replace all of the code above with:

```
for f in sys.argv[1:]:
```

Now you need some outside tool that can gather the paths and run your script. (Ideally batching as many paths as possible into each script execution.)

If you can rely on Windows Desktop Search having indexed the drive, it should only need to do a quick database operation to find all files under a certain path with a certain extension. I have no idea how to write a batch file that runs that query and gets the results as a list of arguments to pass to a Python script (or a PowerShell file that runs the query and passes the results to IronPython without serializing it into a list of arguments), but it would be worth researching this before anything else.

If you can't rely on your platform's desktop search index, on any POSIX platform, it would almost certainly be fastest and simplest to use this one-liner shell script:

```
find /my/path -name '*.tnt' -exec myscript.py {} +
```

Unfortunately, you're not on a POSIX platform, you're on Windows, which doesn't come with the `find` tool, which is the thing that's doing all the heavy lifting here.

There are ports of find to native Windows, but you'll have to figure out the command-line intricaties to get everything quoted right and format the path and so on, so you can write the one-liner batch file. Alternatively, you could install cygwin and use the exact same shell script you'd use on a POSIX system. Or you could find a more Windows-y tool that does what you need.

This could conceivably be slower rather than faster—Windows isn't designed to execute lots of little processes with as little overhead as possible, and I believe it has smaller limits on command lines than platforms like linux or OS X, so you may spend more time waiting for the interpreter to start and exit than you save. You'd have to test to see. In fact, you probably want to test both native and cygwin versions (with both native and cygwin Python, in the latter case).

You don't actually *have* to move the `find` invocation into a batch/shell script; it's probably the simplest answer, but there are others, such as using `subprocess` to call `find` from within Python. This might solve performance problems caused by starting the interpreter too many times.

Getting the right amount of parallelism may also help—spin off each invocation of your script to the background and don't wait for them to finish. (I believe on Windows, the shell isn't involved in this; instead there's a tool named something like "run" that kicks off a process detached from the shell. But I don't remember the details.)

If none of this works out, you may have to write a custom C extension that does the fastest possible Win32 or .NET thing (which also means you have to do the research to find out what that is…) so you can call that from within Python.